# Identical button element and anchor link

Tags: css

I have a delete button inside a form element right next to an edit anchor link. The HTML code looks like:

```
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
<a href="#" class="button">Edit</a>
```

I have used the following CSS to style these so the look identical:

```
/* From html5reset.org */

a {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline; 
    background: transparent;   
}

/* Custom*/

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #EB8E0B;
}

a.button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 9px 15px; 
    background: #617798;  
    border: 0;  
    font: normal 18px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    color: #FFF;
}

/* From html5reset.org */

button, input, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
}

button {
    width: auto; 
    overflow: visible;
}

/* Custom */

button[type=submit],
button[type=button] {  
    width: auto;  
    padding: 9px 15px;  
    background: #617798;  
    border: 0;  
    font: normal 18px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    color: #FFF;  
}
```

This renders correctly in IE, Safari, Chrome but not in Firefox. In Firefox the height of the button element is greater than the anchor link.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox does something weird to button elements, try adding this:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! I have to wait a few minutes before SO allows me to accept your answer. Bare with me.

Comment: OMG I have been messing with this issue half a dang day. Wish I could upvote 100x. Thanks so much!